# How to prevent a C# application from accessing the network?

Tags: security, c#-4.0, network-programming

I have a C# application in source code and I am removing the code which accesses the network (intranet and internet).

Just to be really sure that it won't access the network at all, my idea was to remove the security permission for network access. This is done in app.manifest with a  I think, but due to lack of code completion, I don't find the necessary clue.

**What XML do I have to add to app.manifest in order to prevent my C# application from using any network functionality?**

It should still be able to access the local file system.

Answer (score 0):

The App.manifest contains several entries.

- internetClient
- internetClientServer
- privateNetworkClientServer

You can find a lot of details here, but essentially need to remove these entries and your app will not have networking permissions anymore.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770532.aspx